# Was I correct in calculating this vertex point and subsequent quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, graphing-functions

I drew out the parabola and attached it below just in case it helps. The maximum height of the parabola was given at $18$, the starting point of the parabola was given at $(0,0)$ and the ending point of the parabola (where it encounters the x-axis again) was given at $(18,0)$.

I wrote out the x coordinate to be $9$ only because the graph peaks exactly half way through but is this correct? Seems too simple.

A further question which was asked was to find the actual quadratic equation of this graph. I also tried that out with the three points $(0,0),(18,0),(9,18)$. Using the formula $y=ax^2+bx+c$ I substituted all of the values and got the answer $y=\frac{-324}{1458}x^2+\frac{5832}{1458}x+0$

(reference for how I worked this out is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMl8VHt1nU4)

Comment: "and the ending point of the parabola (where it encounters the x-axis again) was given at $(18,20)$." The point $(18,20)$ is not on the x- axis. Did you mean $(18,0)$?

Comment: Ah yep, edited it, dont know why I put that

Comment: Ok, general form of a quadratic with the roots $x_1, x_2$ is $y=a (x-x_1)(x-x_2)$. Here we have $y=a x(x-18)$. You can find $a$ by plugging in $x$ and $y$ of the vertex point. (Note that here $a$ should be negative).

Comment: @Alyna-KuteaeyvaXX That simplifies to $\,y = -\frac{2}{9}x(x-18)\,$, which may point you to a more direct way.

Comment: @Etemon okay that does help point me thankyou, so was the vertex point correct then? Also, I thought the final answer of $y=−3241458x2+58321458x+0$ was correct?

Comment: @Alyna-KuteaeyvaXX If it is given that the vertex point is $(9,18)$ you can find quadratic equation problem in a way I explained in the previous comment. But if it is only given that quadratic passes through $(0,0)$ , $(18,0)$ then the only thing we can conclude is that vertex has the form $(9,y_0)$. The value of $y_0$ depends on $a$ in $y=ax(x-18)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:
$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
and substitute the equation above with three coordinates which are $(0,0)$, $(9,18)$ and $(18,0)$ and you will get three equations.
$$\left(0,0\right)\::\:c=0$$
$$\left(9,18\right)\::\:81a+9b+c=18$$
$$\left(18,0\right)\::\:324a+18b+c=0$$
Substitute $c=0$ for the second and third equation
$$81a+9b=18$$
$$324a+18b=0$$
Since this is an easy linear system, you should know how to solve it. So, the value is
$$a=-\frac{2}{9}$$
$$b=4$$
$$c=0$$
The equation is:
$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
$$y=-\frac{2}{9}x^2+4x$$

Image reference is below:
[image]